# Highchart data from ajax its not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I am using the below code to display the pie chart, data from generic handler. Data come from generic handler but the chart not displayed. Please help me to do this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //            try {
        var chart;
        //var mytables = $.ajax({ url: 'Handler/ChartHandler.ashx?Type=PayableCount', async: false, success: function (data, result) { if (!result) alert('Failure to retrieve the data.'); } }).responseText;
        //alert(mytables);
        function requestData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Handler/ChartHandler.ashx?Type=PayableCount',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {

                    //var mytables = JSON.parse(data);
                    return [{ "name": "CHE-TELUGU", "value": 123,"y": 10.8},{"name": "CHE-CORPORATE","value": 45,"y": 40.8},{"name": "CHE-MALAYALAM","selected": true,"sliced": true,"value": 155,"y": 12.8},{"name": "CHE-OPERATION","value": 20,"y": 60.8},{"name": "TRY-OPERATION","value": 20,"y": 60.8}];
                    if (!result) alert('Failure to retrieve the data.');
                }
            }).responseText;
        }

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'curpayable',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: 1, //null
                plotShadow: false,                    
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.value}</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.value}',
                        style: {
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Payable Count',
                data: []
            }]
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is my updated code kindly check and give any solution.

Comment: Do you see any error on browser(debug console) ??

Comment: @user2767299 I have update my code. Kindly check and update me.

Comment: Show the data ? is it key value form ?

Comment: { name: 'CHE-TELUGU', value: 123, y: 10.8 },{ name: 'CHE-CORPORATE', value: 45, y: 40.8 },{name: 'CHE-MALAYALAM',value: 155,y: 12.8,sliced: true,selected: true},{ name: 'CHE-OPERATION', value: 20, y: 60.8 },{ name: 'TRY-OPERATION', value: 20, y: 60.8 }

Comment: so you want to use NAME and Value to plot chart ?

Comment: embed your data in square bracket and try [{ name: 'CHE-TELUGU', value: 123, y: 10.8 },{ name: 'CHE-CORPORATE', value: 45, y: 40.8 },{name: 'CHE-MALAYALAM',value: 155,y: 12.8,sliced: true,selected: true},{ name: 'CHE-OPERATION', value: 20, y: 60.8 },{ name: 'TRY-OPERATION', value: 20, y: 60.8 }] like this

Comment: with your data chart works perfectly for me. Add your HTML part of required code.

Comment: @user2767299 Can you post your code here..

Comment: Did you get the data from generic handler?. If i use the data directly to the serious data means work perfectly.Otherwise its not working.

Comment: First make sure that you have data form your AJAX call in RIGHT format, also you have the <DIV> with ID "curpayable" .

Comment: I have checked that if you give data in wrong format then it shows nothing.!!!

Comment: Please see my updated code (requestData()). If i manually return the string from request data function. But its not working brother..

Comment: Well, I don't know why your AJAX looks that way, but a couple of questions: `1)` Does title show up, when you set some kind of title? `2)` Have you tried to use `$(..).highcharts().series[0].setData(data)` ? `3)` Have you tried another solution, like described in [one of tutorials](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json#3) on Highcharts page?

Comment: @user2767299 i posted my full javascript code here. Please check and update me.

Comment: Please, answer my questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is code :

On load called the function with testdata, but you  can remove that and do the required changes for below ajax call.

Please do the formatting changes as per your need.

**Check :**  http://jsfiddle.net/Y7HPD/

```
     $(function() {
    drawPie([
    ['ONETOUCH   DEVICE', 27.78],
    ['FREESTYLE  DEVICE', 20.83],
    ['Nova Max  Test Strips  ', 11.11],
    ['ONETOUCH   DEVICE 2PK', 11.11]
]);

 $.post('your URL', {
    delay: 1
}, function (data) {
    drawPie(data);
}, 'json');
});


function drawPie(dd) {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: dd

    }]
});
};
```